# Get Class and object type from linq list query

Tags: c#, linq, scom

I am trying to get the underlying type from a linq query running against the type's `GetFields` method. In my example, i have:

```
string mClass = "Computer"; //match string
var t = typeof(SystemMonitoringClass);
var monitoringClass = (SystemMonitoringClass)t.GetFields().First(x => x.Name == mClass);
```

The casting in my 3rd line fails as i can't convert the returning type `FieldInfo` into what i am looking for. So after finding the right field,  how can i get the actual object. This workaround is due to the new SCOM 2012 SDK changing `SystemMonitoringClass` from an enum to a class. If someone has a better approach to match a string and get the actual monitoring object or field in this case, that would also work.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh326622.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the concepts of "the field" from "the value of that field for a particular instance". You want [`FieldInfo.GetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx), e.g.

```
var monitoringClass = (SystemClass) field.GetValue(null);
```

EDIT: I note that `SystemMonitoringClass.Computer` is actually declared to return a value of type `SystemClass`, not `SystemMonitoringClass` - so you may want to change your cast appropriately, as I have above.

Comment: Do i then need to cast `(SystemMonitoringClass)FieldInfo.GetValue`?

Comment: @Warz: Yes, as `GetValue` is declared to return `object`.

Comment: I am not sure what your doing here with `var monitoringClass = (SystemMonitoringClass) field.GetValue(instance);` what is instance supposed to be

Comment: @Warz: The instance you're getting the field value from. If this is a *static* field, you can pass in null instead.

Comment: @Warz: Now that I've followed your link, it looks like it *is* a static field, so I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, all those static fields return `SystemClass`. Thanks for the find